# How to prevent React function component from flashing during async request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Before the React function component below returns any JSX, it checks AWS Cognito for the current user. The user data is fetched asynchronously, so the markup for no user flashes quickly before the component re-renders with the JSX for a logged in user.

What is the proper way to avoid this type of flashing? Is there a better way of fetching data asynchronously before rendering function components?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function Component() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(true);

    async function checkUser() {
        try {
            const data = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
            const userInfo = { username: data.username, ...data.attributes, }
            setUser(userInfo);
        } catch (err) { console.log('error: ', err) }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUser();
    }, []);


    if(user) {
        return <p>Logged in user content</p>
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: I guess the code you have posted is incomplete or lacks some crucial data because atm the "When user is logged in..." part is never rendered. (user is always truthy)

Comment: If user is set to `useState(null)`, then it does not work. But when initilizing as `true`, the JSX in the second return flashes quickly. This is why I am confused.

Comment: It definitely should be set to `null` when the component mounts. Its still unclear though why the content flashes.

Comment: The reason it is set to null is because if the second return statement returns a redirect to a login form, then it will always redirect. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

your can add state for loader and show loading when request is in progress.

```
function Component() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)


    async function checkUser() {
        setLoading(true) 
        try {
            const data = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
            const userInfo = { username: data.username, ...data.attributes, }
            setUser(userInfo);
            setLoading(false)
        } catch (err) { console.log('error: ', err); setLoading(false) }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUser();
    }, []);

    if(isLoading) return <p>Loading... </p>

    if(user) {
        return <p>Logged in user content</p>
    } else {
        return <p>When the user is logged in, this content flashes quickly.</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is just a workaround to the problem.

Comment: I think this pattern is used for client side applications. From your code above you are trying to get the current user so meanwhile you have to show indicator that your are loading. are you expecting to not render anything while it's in progress?

Comment: Adding a loader is a good advice, but still we dont know why the content flashes.

Comment: shouldn't   `const [user, setUser] = useState(true);` actually be `false`